# Uso do async com .NET Core e nHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, async, nhibernate, .net-core

No .NET Core sei que temos o `async` e `await` para *request async*.

Até ai tudo bem, mas muitos *frameworks* no mercado estão criando métodos com a assinatura `MetodoAsync()` e tem o método sem ser `async Metodo()`.

Podemos utilizar `async` assim

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<JsonResult> Get()
{
    return await Task.Run(() => Json(_fachadaGrupo.BuscarTodos()));
}
```

Lembrando que nos métodos internos `_fachadaGrupo.BuscarTodos()`. não existem o método *async* ele utiliza uma conexão com banco de dados nHibernate e o mesmo não tem o método `Async()` no momento. Logo então queria saber se isso  ainda tem a mesma eficiência e a mesma logica acontece internamente no qual a *thread* e liberada para novas *requests*. Ou se dá no mesmo que não ter.

```
 // facade
    public IEnumerable<GrupoDto> BuscarTodos()
    {
        return _buscarTodos.Buscar();
    }


    // Serviço
    public IEnumerable<GrupoDto> Buscar()
            {
                IRepositorioGrupo repositorioGrupo = new RepositorioGrupo(_nHibernateHelper);

                return repositorioGrupo.Lista(_usuario);
            }

// repositorio 
public IEnumerable<GrupoDto> Lista(Usuario usuario)
        {
            Usuario usuarioAlias = null;
            Grupo grupo = null;
            GrupoDto grupoDto = null;

            return Sessao.QueryOver(() => grupo).JoinAlias(() => grupo.Usuario, () => usuarioAlias)
                .SelectList(list => list.Select(() => grupo.Id).WithAlias(() => grupoDto.Id)
                .Select(() => grupo.Descricao).WithAlias(() => grupoDto.Descricao))
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<GrupoDto>())
                .Where(g => g.Usuario == usuario).OrderBy(g => g.Id).Desc.List<GrupoDto>();
        }
```

Comment: se quiser continuar à utilizar o ASP.NET Core, te aconselho a abandonar o NHibernate, o mesmo possui uma dependência com o `Iesi.Collections` que não sofre atualização há alguns anos, as `ISession` não são `thread safe`, que torna inviável implementar o `async/wait` com o mesmo, e por fim, o mesmo não foi feito no `.net standard`, você pode até utilizar o mesmo em modo de `compatibilidade` com o `4.6.1`, mas você não terá garantias... então te aconselho a utilizar o `EF Core 2.0`, que inclusive é bem mais eficiente e tem uma API bem mais madura.

Comment: Esta em curso uma compatibilidade com .net standard , e na versão que esta prestes a ser lancada já vamos ter suporte a async/wait (versão 5.0 dele) https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/693 (versão 5.0) e na versão 5.1 provavelmente teremos já suporte com .net standard https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/633

Comment: Me desculpe, mas este NH 5.0 está sendo desenvolvido já há algum tempo, e sempre sendo adiado. A menos que o seu projeto só venha a entrar em produção em 2022, não é uma boa idéia esperar por uma versão estável do mesmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método `BuscarTodos()` obviamente nunca executará assincronamente. O seu `Get()` executará assim quando for chamado com um `await`, a não ser que seja modificado. Como ele é muito simples e só chama outro método síncrono, não haverá ganho. O ganho se daria só neste método, entre o seu próprio código que é quase indivisível.

A assincronicidade que deseja tem que ser realizada dentro do `BuscarTodos()`, mais precisamente nesta conexão com o banco de dados. A utilidade real dele provavelmente será ter um método assíncrono que faz acesso ao recurso externo dentro dele e isto me parece que o NHibernate é que deveria fornecer, mas aí já começo entrar na especulação, não vi o código.

Com a edição nota-se que é dentro do `Lista()`que a "mágica" deve acontecer, é ali no LINQ que deveria ser assíncrono para obter ganhos.

Eu ia escrever o mesmo que o Tobias Mesquita, mas evitei porque o EF Core ainda não está 100% pronto, mesmo no 2.0, mas eu trocaria de ORM, mesmo assim considero ele melhor. Gosto da coragem de quem reconhece que uma arquitetura está errada e começa do zero como a Microsoft fez. Seria ótimo que o NHibernate fizesse o mesmo. Ele não tem problemas isolados. Esses produtos foram criados quando não se sabia tudo o que precisava sobre ORM, os mais modernos são bem mais vantajosos por terem aprendido lições.

Comment: acabei de adicionar mais código para melhor detalhamento, teria como explicar como funciona isso?

Comment: Entendi, obrigado, no meu caso especifico utilizo a muito tempo nhibernate. Foi utilizar entity core na versão 1.2 ou 1.1 se não me engano. Me lembro de ter esbarrado numa limitação de relações 1..1 não gostei nem um pouco. Lembro que a mesma limitação estava no roadmap para 2.0 então já deve estar tudo OK. Mas como vi os pull no nhibernate e eu mesmo compilo ele no momento, então sim utilizo ele para .net standard (ahh roberto esta longe de ficar 100% , tem 6mil testes quase, presumi que no banco que uso passou em todos ta ok). Ainda no pull .net standard falta os async. Vou reletar isso lá.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção, andei lendo sobre o async await achei isso aqui, sou ruim no inglês ainda. Mas estou correndo atrás de entender esse artigo lendo mais de uma vez. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx